# How do I make my navigation bar transparent in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, uinavigationbar

I want to make my navigation controller like this. My main view should continue to the top.
[image]

But when I am trying implement it I get this result:
[image]

How can I handle this problem. I want to implement something like in first image. Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: I only try to make it transparent from the main.storyboard. Not tried any code-wise

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use this in my Apps to make my navigationBar transparent (if the navigationBar is in a UINavigationController):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Now you can still add buttons and a title to your navigationBar.

**EDIT: Swift 3 (Thanks to DrBreakalot)**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(‌​UIImage(), for: .default) 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Comment: Swift3:  

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have your title and button in your view, it looks like you want to hide the navigation bar rather than make it transparent. If you don't want the navigation bar on any of your screens you can uncheck 'Shows Navigation Bar' in the Storyboard.

Or, if you only want to hide the navigation bar on certain screens, you can set it in viewDidLoad()

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will help get you going. What you're doing is creating a `UIVisualEffectView` that is going to blur things a bit, then you're setting it as a subview to the `navBar`.

```
func addBlurEffect() {
    let bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
    visualEffectView.frame = bounds
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Autolayout is set to the top margin instead of to the view top. You also should change the status bar like so in the `AppDelegate`

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```